# Adding beta tester: Provisioning profile can't be found

Tags: iphone, distribution, provisioning, beta-testing

I'm going crazy with all certificates, provisioning profiles etc... !!!

So... for my app i need some beta tester. 
I created correctly all the provisioning profiles (development and distribution): in the distribution profile i added my device and one other.
It worked fine, my beta tester can try the app.

Now i need to add other beta tester: i went to the provisioning portal -> Devices, and i added other six udid.
I edited the distribution profile, adding the new udids.
I re-downloaded the profile (erasing, before, the old one)... and now, if i run the app (selecting the distribution profile), xcode returns me an error

```
Code Sign error: Provisioning profile '666DA327-945B-4ED3-A08B-EDC0F28EB9E2' can't be found
```

Why?
Thanks!

Comment: No, solved! in "target -> my_app" it was selected the old distribution profile (even if i updated on "project -> info"). Now it works! :)

Answer (score -1):

You must download certificate with your appId and then com.yourcompany.yourapplicationName with this name then and then you are able to configure your application.

Keep smiling...